# Perl extract between start and end

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I am aiming to extract a string from start to an end word, (`dIonly` is start and should be the end workset [including these parenthesis]; furthermore I would like to print the output into a file named `report`.
I have had problems with lookbehind, as the variable length was not implemented.
Now I reversed the string, to do lookahead. However, something is still not working.

I need to start from dIonly which means I have to reverse the string to circumvent the problem described above, as there are many workset(( in the whole string, which means I can't start from there...

Thank you! I edited the script now. What I need to do is reverse the string. I did that by splitting the string with a space as delimiter into a list, then reversed it, and put it into a string again. Just to split it into a list again at the delimiter 'solution' as my output will have several strings of which I want to extract dIonly to workset (this only works once the string is reversed as otherwise I would encouter worksets that I do not want and extract a different string, as dIonly is a distinct part of the pattern of the solution from which I can work forward to the second workset (which itself is the first workset with 2 parenthesis). Then I want to print it to a new output file. Any suggestions welcome!

This is a sample of the data: 
... denotes that it continues after

> ```
> ..... maxRiskC(cA, 3)) c workset((RiskCA(cA, 3), RiskCB(cB, 2), maxRiskC(cA, 3))) c RiskCA(cA, 3) c RiskCB(cB, 2)) ***********
> ```
>
> equation (built-in equation for symbol *<=*) 6 <= 40 ---> true
>   Solution 4 (state 31) states: 40  rewrites: 8421 in 5357394502ms cpu
>   (1464ms  real) (0) rewrites/second) G:Game --> workset(empty) c playA
>   c dIonly c
>           .....

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# perl -d ./perl_debugger.pl


use strict;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use File::Slurp;


my @a_linesorig;
my @a_out;
my @a_str;
my $line;
my $reversedline;
my @a_linesrev;
my @reversedarray;
my $reversedline;
my $str;

open(my $fh, "<", "data.txt")
    or die "cannot open < data.txt: $!";


    my $line = read_file('data.txt');


   @a_linesorig = split(' ', $line);
   @a_linesrev = reverse(@a_linesorig);
   $reversedline = join(' ', @a_linesrev); # joins the reversed list to a single string again
   @reversedarray = split( /solution/, $reversedline ); # should split huge string into a list from one solution to next


    foreach $str (@reversedarray)  {
      if ($str =~ /\bdIonly:\b(.*?)\bworkset\b/g);      
         print Dumper \$str;
         print (@a_out, "$str");

       }  





close $fh
  or die "can't close file: $!";

open(my $fh, ">", "output.txt")
    or die "cannot open > output.txt: $!";

foreach $str (@a_out)
{
   print ($fh "$str\n");
}

close $fh
  or die "can't close file: $!";
```

Comment: sample data? have you tried http://regex101.com/ ?

Comment: your code isn't doing lookahead, so there's no reason for the reverse

Comment: I don't see lookahead and lookbehind in your data. Please, give a minimal example of what are you trying to achieve. Without files and any parasite code

Comment: Reindented your code. Somewhere, you're missing a closing curly brace.

Comment: Also, you don't need both `use 5.10;` and `use 5.12;`

Comment: thank you i have not tried regex101...never heard about it actually!

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. I have included a sample part of the string I am trying to analyze. I thought I would reverse the string because I need to start from dIonly as the string contains lots of workset(( in it. Hence I wanted to reverse the string so I could start from dIonly and then get the first workset with two parenthesis following right after. Thanks for the suggestions so far!

Answer (score 0):

Take off the reverse, it will reverse letters also and not individual words, for that scalar. 
You can try it with a greedy match since you are only interested in the last workset:

```
while (my $line = <$input>) { 
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /.*workset(.*dIonly)/) {
            # do something with results
            say $fh "'$1'";
            }
}
```

And if you need to reverse before writing to the file, you can do:

```
while (my $line = <$input>) { 
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /.*workset(.*dIonly)/) {
            say $fh join " ",reverse (split / /,$1);
            }
}
```

Comment: I believe I did not give a good example. There are worksets all over the string, it is huge. Hence what I wanted to do is to reverse the string (which is apparently not possible) before I search for the substring, so I would be able to extract from dIonly to the first workset with two parenthesis attached workset((.

I think my problem is more related to reversing the string and then I was thinking if I could reverse only the words not the letters of the string I could maybe extract  \bdIonly:\b(...)?=\bworkset\(\(\b/g

Comment: @user3290016 Is the file multiple lines? Is it one `donly` per individual line?

Comment: the file has multiple lines but only one dIonly per individual line. However a few worksets per line. And I wanted to actually use lookback to go from dIonly to the first workset with two parentheses, but it did not work...

Comment: @user3290016 See edit on the regex match, its actually not as complicated as you are making it out to be.

Comment: thank you, but for some reason it still does not work, well i am going to look into it for another day i guess...

Comment: @user3290016 Can you edit with what your script looks like now?

Comment: Hey salparadise, Thank you I edited the script, and put an additional explanation of my thoughts and problems with the code. Maybe I am having troubles with understanding how to loop. If you need any further explanation please let me know. And thanks a lot for your help!